# Different summary total from dimension year,month and channel grouping from google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I got a rare problem with our account, I using google API v3 to get data from google analytics.

the first request using dimension ga:year ga:month

second request using dimension ga:channelGrouping

both requests have a similar for another parameter:

start date (2015-07-17) end date (2019-11-27)

metrics `a:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalConversionRateAll,ga:goalValueAll,ga:sessions,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:users,ga:pageviews`

and different summary start when start date under 27 Sept 2017

has anyone experienced the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the large period of time analyzed and that you are querying a non-standard report, it's likely that you're getting **sampled data**.

About data sampling: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

You can specify the sampling level to use for a request by setting the *samplingLevel* parameter: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

You can understand if a Core Reporting API response contains sampled data by ***containsSampledData*** field in the response (in this case the containsSampledData response field will be *true*).

Note: Data is sampled when reports that include the Users and Active Users metrics include data from before September 2016.

Comment: i have tried to add samplingLevel parameter but I can't find the different.
so is possible to make summary totals with the same result?

FYI:
the summary totals from dimension ga:year ga:month higher than dimension ga:channelGrouping

Comment: and this happens in Google Analytics API only, in GA analytics dashboard show correct summary totals

Comment: May depend on samplingLevel or number of rows in result (with API you can get up to 10.000 rows of information for a single request).